# Apache Http Client 4.5 Authentication Exception when Integrating to ServiceNow

Tags: apache, authentication, servicenow

Am trying to connect to my service-now instance using Apache Client 4.5 via a proxy server. Unfortunately the connection is failing with the below exception.

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
{"error":{"message":"User Not Authenticated","detail":"Required to provide Auth information"},"status":"failure"}

I can understand that this is because of authentication exception, but i did seem to have provide the credential as shown below.

Code Snippet :

```
public void getRequestWithProxy() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
{
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope("proxy.xxxx.com", 0000),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("proxyuser", "proxypassword"));
    credsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope("instance.service-now.com", 443),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
    try {
        HttpHost target = new HttpHost("instance.service-now.com", 443, "https");
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxy.xxxx.com", 0000);

        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setProxy(proxy)
            .build();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("/api/now/table/incident");
        httpget.setConfig(config);

        System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine() + " to " + target + " via " + proxy);

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, httpget);
        try {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
}
```

I assume that i have access to the URL am accessing, because the same URL "https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident" when tried in browser works fine using SSO (Single Sing On).

Please help me with what am missing.

Thanks in advance for your help in this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You stated it was a URL. new AuthScope should be a hostname and not a URL.